# " much to someone's amazement " vs " (to) much of the amazement of someone "

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I'd like to ask if the following sentences are have the same meaning and all of them are grammatically correct?

> 1. Much to my surprise, they offered me a £4,000 scholarship.
> 2. To much of the surprise of my, they offered me a £4,000 scholarship.
> 3. Much of the surprise of my, they offered me a £4,000 scholarship.
> 4. Much of the surprise of mine, they offered me a £4,000 scholarship.

---

I found some [example](http://www.skyscrapercity.com/showthread.php?t=1081955&page=9) sentences that were created using by " to much of the amazement" and I would like to ask which one is more correct when we refer to 3rd person or other people without using  personal pronouns as follows.

> Much of the amazement of the historians, a recently unearthed
>   fortnightly in the extinct Arabic-Malayalam language reveals that the
>   Muslim community in Malabar was very much concerned about the
>   developments in different sectors of the Ottoman Empire.(original sentence)
>
> **To much of  the amazement of the historians**, a recently unearthed
>   fortnightly in the extinct Arabic-Malayalam language reveals that the
>   Muslim community in Malabar was very much concerned about the
>   developments in different sectors of the Ottoman Empire.
>
> **Much to the amazement of the historians**, a recently unearthed
>   fortnightly in the extinct Arabic-Malayalam language reveals that the
>   Muslim community in Malabar was very much concerned about the
>   developments in different sectors of the Ottoman Empire.
>
> **Much to the historians' amazement**, a recently unearthed
>   fortnightly in the extinct Arabic-Malayalam language reveals that the
>   Muslim community in Malabar was very much concerned about the
>   developments in different sectors of the Ottoman Empire.

Another [example](http://www.bviplatinum.com/news.php?articleId=1438343912) I found on the Internet is as follows:

> ...Adorya Baly, who brought the late national hero Noel Lloyd back to
>   life in her performance, much of the amazement of the audience.
>
> ...Adorya Baly, who brought the late national hero Noel Lloyd back to
>   life in her performance, **(to) much to  the amazement of the audience**.
>
> ...Adorya Baly, who brought the late national hero Noel Lloyd back to
>   life in her performance, **much to  the audience's amazement**.

Answer (score 1):

Number 1 sounds fine; numbers 2–4  are almost unintelligible.

*of my* should be followed by something, typically a noun. *To the surprise of my family, ...* would be grammatically correct, but conveys a different meaning.